# Tensorflow and Scikit learn: Same solution but different outputs

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, tensorflow-estimator

Im implementing a simple linear regression with scikitlearn and tensorflow.

My solution in scikitlearn seem fine but with tensorflow my evaluation output is showing some crazy numbers.

The problem is basically to try to predict a salary based in years of experience.

I not sure what Im doing wrong in Tensorflow's code.

Thanks!

**ScikitLearn solution**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv') 

X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = data.iloc[:, 1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

X_single_data = [[4.6]]
y_single_pred = regressor.predict(X_single_data)

print(f'Train score: {regressor.score(X_train, y_train)}')
print(f'Test  score: {regressor.score(X_test, y_test)}')
```

> Train score: 0.960775692121653
>
> Test  score: 0.9248580247217076

**Tensorflow solution**

```
import tensorflow as tf

f_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='X', shape=[1])]
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=f_cols)


train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'X': X_train}, y=y_train,shuffle=False)

test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'X': X_test}, y=y_test,shuffle=False)


train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=test_input_fn)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

> ({'average_loss': 7675087400.0,
>
> 'label/mean': 84588.11,
>
> 'loss': 69075790000.0,
>
> 'prediction/mean': 5.0796494,
>
> 'global_step': 6},
>
> [])

**Data**

```
YearsExperience,Salary
1.1,39343.00
1.3,46205.00
1.5,37731.00
2.0,43525.00
2.2,39891.00
2.9,56642.00
3.0,60150.00
3.2,54445.00
3.2,64445.00
3.7,57189.00
3.9,63218.00
4.0,55794.00
4.0,56957.00
4.1,57081.00
4.5,61111.00
4.9,67938.00
5.1,66029.00
5.3,83088.00
5.9,81363.00
6.0,93940.00
6.8,91738.00
7.1,98273.00
7.9,101302.00
8.2,113812.00
8.7,109431.00
9.0,105582.00
9.5,116969.00
9.6,112635.00
10.3,122391.00
10.5,121872.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your code request in the comments: Though I had used my online curve and surface fitting web site zunzun.com for this equation at http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/Sigmoidal/Sigmoid%20B/ for the modeling work, here is a graphing source code example using the scipy differential_evolution genetic algorithm module to estimate initial parameter estimates. The scipy implementation of Differential Evolution uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, which requires bounds within which to search - in this example those bounds are taken from the data maximum and minimum values, and the fit statistics and parameter values are almost identical to those from the web site.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([ 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 2.0, 2.2, 2.9, 3.0, 3.2, 3.2, 3.7, 3.9, 4.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.5, 4.9, 5.1, 5.3, 5.9, 6.0, 6.8, 7.1, 7.9, 8.2, 8.7, 9.0, 9.5, 9.6, 10.3, 10.5])
yData = numpy.array([ 39.343, 46.205, 37.731, 43.525, 39.891, 56.642, 60.15, 54.445, 64.445, 57.189, 63.218, 55.794, 56.957, 57.081, 61.111, 67.938, 66.029, 83.088, 81.363, 93.94, 91.738, 98.273, 101.302, 113.812, 109.431, 105.582, 116.969, 112.635, 122.391, 121.872])


def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a / (1.0 + numpy.exp(-(x-b)/c))


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('Years of experience') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Salary in thousands') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot place an image in a comment, and so place it here. I suspected the relationship might be sigmoidal rather than linear, and found the following sigmoidal equation and fit statistics using units of thousands for salary: "y = a / (1.0 + exp(-(x-b)/c))" with fitted parameters a =  1.5535069418318591E+02, b =  5.4580059234664899E+00, and c =  3.7724942500630938E+00 giving an R-squared = 0.96 and RMSE = 5.30 (thousand)
[image: sigmoidal]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you mind posting your code here?

I put my solution on github, please check how I could find a linear solution solution with scikit learn

https://github.com/gabrielpsilva/ai-study-models/blob/master/salary_linear_regression_sklearn_tensorflow.ipynb

 I'm still on my first steps, learning by examples :)

Comment: I cannot format code in a comment, and so posted it as a second answer.